# How to make a redirection of html files on the htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following urls:

```
http://superawesomedomain.com/recently-created.html
http://superawesomedomain.com/recently-created.html
http://superawesomedomain.com/articles/recently-created.html
http://superawesomedomain.com/surveys/0-6-months.html
```

And I want to redirect them to the following URL:

```
http://superawesomedomain.com/search_redirect?q=recently-created
http://superawesomedomain.com/search_redirect?q=recently-created
http://superawesomedomain.com/search_redirect?q=recently-created
http://superawesomedomain.com/search_redirect?q=0-6-months
```

I have trouble getting the filename (without the extension) and append it to the url that I want.

I have to do the redirect with .htaccess

I'll very thankful for your help.

Comment: have you tried using `Redirect 301`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
/recently-created.html /search_redirect?q=recently-created
/recently-created.html /search_redirect?q=recently-created
/articles/recently-created.html /search_redirect?q=recently-created
/surveys/0-6-months.html /search_redirect?q=0-6-months
```

You should only need to use http://superawesomedomain.com if on another server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following redirect in /root/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?:[^/.]*/)?([^.]+)\.html$ http://domain.com/search_redirect/?q=$1
```

This will redirect

```
/foo/bar.html
```

or

```
/bar.html
```

to

```
/search_redirect/?q=bar
```

If you want to make the redirect Permanent ,change the statust code **302** to **301** .

Refrence :
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html